# Update index position of orchard

Tags: javascript

I have been tasked with finding the element within the array which is positioned backwards. So for example in an array with elements 'apple' I need to find the one which is 'elppa' and return the index which it is positioned at.

I'm not sure where im going wrong

```
function findWrongWayFruit(orchard) {
  let position = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < orchard.length; i++) {
    if (orchard[i] === orchard[i].split('').reverse().join('')) {
      position = i;
    }
  }
  return position;
}
```

Comment: What input are you giving? Presumably the condition is never true.

Comment: Using `0` as the initial value of `position` is a bad idea. You can't tell the difference between finding a match in the first element of `orchard` and not finding any match.

Comment: The code works fine. Are strings in "orchard" in lower case or does it follow capitalisation. In case of capitalisation, the position will always be 0.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong way fruit"? This loop looks for elements that are palindromes. It returns the index of the last palindrome in the array.

Comment: I receive the following errors: should return the correct index when the wrong-way fruit is at the end
  ✕ AssertionError: expected +0 to equal 5
 
should return the correct index when the wrong-way fruit is at any other random position
  ✕ AssertionError: expected +0 to equal 1

Comment: Please show the input that generates those errors.

Comment: so for wrong way fruit instead of apple, elppa

Comment: That's not what your code looks for. It looks for strings that are the same forward and backward, like `abcba`

Comment: Please edit the question and add a description of what the function is supposed to do.

Comment: If `orchard` contains both `apple` and `elppa`, you need to compare each element with the reverse of every other element, not the reverse of itself.

Comment: am I not comparing the index which is being looped through to the reverse of the string?